# Free & premium game with both same NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nsuserdefaults

I Want to publish 2 versions of my game, 1 for free with advertisement and 1 premium.

But if the user is in level 9 in the free version and it buys the premium, than it should begin from level 9 in the premium version.

How do I do this?

Comment: Better to use in-app-purchase so you wouldn't need 2 different applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the ability to share NSUserDefaults suites between applications.

```
[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"yourGroupIdentifier"];
```

To enable your apps for this functionality you need to enable App Groups in your targets:

- Select the project file in the Xcode Project Navigator
- Select your target
- Select the tab Capabilities
- Enable App Groups and give it a name ("yourGroupIdentifier")

Initialising NSUserDefaults as shown above in both your apps will enable you to read and write the same defaults from both apps.

Having said that, I would suggest to use an In-App Purchase to unlock the pro version, instead of having 2 different products; for a better user experience.